# Changing font-color when hovering div

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm trying to make a div with text within it that is going to change whenever the user hovers over the `div` area, and not only the `p` tag. I am however not able to make my solution work.

[**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5ULpy/)

```
div{
  height:200px;
  width:400px;
  background-color:#fbfb2b;    
}

div:hover + p{
  color:#fff;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Take away the `+` symbol in your css:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5ULpy/1/)

CSS:

```
div{
  height:200px;
  width:400px;
  background-color:#fbfb2b;    
}

div:hover p{
  color:#fff;
}
```

If you were looking for the selector which means direct descendant of `div`, you wanted `>`.

eg:

```
div:hover > p{
  /*styles*/
}
```

Which would have worked for:

```
<div>
  <p>Stuff</p>
</div>
```

But not

```
<div>
  <span>
    <p>Incorrect HTML example</p>
  </span>
</div>
```

With your current CSS, you're trying to select the sibling.

If your HTML was like this:

```
<div></div>
<p>Some piece of text that is gonna change color when hovering the div</p>
```

the colour of `p` would have changed.

Ultimately however, with this specific HTML, you don't even need to include the `p` in the css and can just do `div:hover`, but if you're going to have other elements in it, then you should keep the `p`.

Answer (score 1):

You must read rule about *descendant selectors* [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors).
If you need more info about [selectors in css](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

---

### Solved:

```
div:hover p{
  color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take out the + P

```
div:hover {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your css you have used like this.

```
div:hover + p{
 color:#fff;
}
```

It means you are applying the hover style for the siblings element not child element. In your case you need to remove + and add just space.

[**SIBLINGS ELEMENT PROVED HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/5ULpy/8/)

```
div:hover p{
 color:#fff;
}
```

[**CHILD ELEMENT PROVED HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/5ULpy/9/)

Answer (score 1):

there is no need to mention the `<p>` at all you can simply state the colour of all child elements by setting the style on the parent:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cZj6E/)

```
div:hover {
  color:#fff;
}
```

However if you did just want to target the paragraph text only you would use a > (child combinator) to target the P ONLY.

Answer (score 0):

Your Css:

```
div:hover + p{
  color:#fff;
}
```

`+` selector select all `<p>` elements that are placed immediately after `<div>` elements.

[Demo Fiddle With "+" selector](http://jsfiddle.net/5ULpy/25/)

You can see, In the above fiddle `div:hover + p` select the outer `<p>` element, which are placed immediately after `<div>` elements.

But in your Case you do not need to use `+` selector. Because you want to select the child element of hovered div.

So, you should try this:

```
div:hover p{    
   color:#fff;
}
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/5ULpy/23/)